# Regular expression for checking if string is a-zA-Z0-9

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check if a string is all `a-zA-Z0-9` but this is not working. Any idea why?

```
var pattern=/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/;
var myString='125 jXw';  // this shouldn't be accepted
var matches=pattern.exec(myString);
var matchStatus=1;  // say matchStatus is true

if(typeof matches === 'undefined'){
  alert('within here');
  matchStatus=0; // matchStatus is false
};

if(matchStatus===1){
  alert("there was a match");
}
```

Comment: Your string has a white space so it doesn't match your pattern.

Comment: var pattern=/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*$/;

Comment: tab value is not filter, I copy from text editor with tab, eg. 'test%  $test', space is with 2 tab, but its not filter at all, result as 'test  test'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) returns `null` if no match is found, which is `typeof` object not `undefined`.

You should use this:

```
var matches = pattern.exec(myString); // either an array or null
var matchStatus = Boolean(matches);

if (matchStatus)
    alert("there was a match");
else
    alert('within here');
```

Or just use the [`test` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

```
var matchStatus = pattern.test(myString); // a boolean
```

Answer (score 1):

If im not wrong, your regex has no provision for SPACE and your string has space in it. If you want to allow space try this way /^[a-zA-z0-9\ ]*$/

Comment: No need in escaping space in a set.

Comment: Exactly.. or better /^[a-zA-z0-9\s]*$/

Comment: @ZiaudDeen: The OPs problem is not that the regex does not match (this is intended), but that `matchStatus` does not get set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if(matches === null){
  alert('within here');
  matchStatus=0; // matchStatus is false
};

if(matchStatus===1){
  alert("there was a match");
}
```

Regex.exec returns null if there's no match, not undefined.  So you need to test that.

It seems to work as you expect like that: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prsdf/)

Documentation for `exec`: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

Answer (score 1):

```
function KeyString(elm)
{
    var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/;

    if( !elm.value.match(pattern))
    {
        alert("require a-z and 0-9");
        elm.value='';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would test it only - in this case:

```
var pattern = /^[a-z0-9]+$/i;
var myString = '125 jXw';
var matchStatus = 1;  // say matchStatus is true

if (!pattern.test(matches)) {
    matchStatus = 0; // matchStatus is false
};

if(matchStatus === 1){
    alert("there was a match");
}
```